# How to fetch multiple data from mysql database with only one query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am working on a PHP project, I have a table Attendee with profession column in it, I am trying to make a chart of the percentage of profession of the attendees, `select count(*) from Attendee where Profession = 'Nurse'` for example, but I have like 10 professions so is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Try something like `SELECT Profession, COUNT(*) FROM Attendee GROUP BY Profession`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [group by](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group-by/) SQL functionality.  E.g.

```
select Profession , count(*) num 
from Attendee 
group by Profession;
```

Comment: perfect thank you. can't accept it yet ( in 5 mins) but thank you sir